# Pandas: Rows in colum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a dataframe and I need reestructurate the data.
This is my dataframe

```
data = {'Var1':  ['A', 'A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],
        'Var2': ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
        'value': [500, 1000,600,100,700,200,250,130,890]
         
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Var1','Var2','value'])


    Var1    Var2    value
0   A       A       500
1   A       B       1000
2   A       C       600
3   B       A       100
4   B       B       700
5   B       C       200
6   C       A       250
7   C       B       130
8   C       C       890
```

I need all row in colum Var2 now are in a column index (this):

```
    A    B     C 
A  500  1000  600  
B  100  700   200
C  250  130   890
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: this is  pivot: `df.pivot(*df)`

Comment: @anky sneaky use of `*df` there...

Comment: @anky well done :)